# Changing Value of a TextView From a Class Called From Manifesto

Tags: java, android

I have a class which is being called from the manifesto whenever the device is unplugged or plugged from the USB/power.

I am trying to change the value of a TextView showing the user the status of the device's connection.

This should be a very easy and simple thing, but unfortunately I was unable to locate the answer even after hours of searching.

Here is the code I have: (the commented part is not working)

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED))
        {
            //TextView txtStatus = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
            //txtStatus.setText("Connected");

        }
        else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED))
        {
            //TextView txtStatus = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
           // txtStatus.setText("Disconnected");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the listener pattern, and whichever context contains the views could add itself as a listener to the broadcast receiver, then change the text view when an event gets fired.

Comment: You could also try using [Observables](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html), and have the relevant activity listen to those observables.

Comment: Thanks for the message, but I'm afraid that I am so much very new to android development that I'm unable to solve this without someone sending me some code example....

Comment: Can you add some more information to your question? Perhaps the Activity/Fragment whose content view contains the TextViews you want to change? Is your broadcast receiver registered in the manifest, or in an 
activity, or somewhere else? It's difficult to provide a code example without more information.

Comment: thanks for replying, below are the answers: Perhaps the Activity/Fragment whose content view contains the TextViews you want to change?  its in the MainActivity (totally plain activity with just a textview in it)  --------------- Is your broadcast receiver registered in the manifest? YES (this works, i mean the class PowerConnectionReceiver works, if i place  toast it shows the messages. but i am trying to change the value of the TEXTVIEW instead) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively easy to update the UI from a broadcast receiver that is registered dynamically (i.e. not in the manifest), but updating it from one registered in the manifest is tricker, as the instance is static.

In theory you could make it observable and add observers, or add a static observable object and listen to that, but I'm not really comfortable doing that in my own code, especially since the manifest receiver isn't guaranteed to exist until it receives its first broadcast. The safest way to do it is probably to add *another* broadcast receiver in your activity, then send a broadcast from your `PowerConnectionReceiver` to the one in your activity. In my example, I'm using a local broadcast receiver (less overhead). So your `PowerConnectionReceiver` would look something like this:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_STATUS_CHANGE = "STATUS_CHANGE";
    public static final String EXTRA_STATUS = "POWER_STATUS";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String status = null;
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)){
            status = "Connected";
        }
        else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)){
           status = "Disconnected";
        }

        if (status == null){
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_STATUS_CHANGE);
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STATUS, status);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

And your activity would look something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private txtStatusView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayoutWithTextView);
        txtStatusView = findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            statusReceiver, new IntentFilter(PowerConnectionReceiver.ACTION_STATUS_CHANGE)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(statusReceiver);
      super.onDestroy();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver statusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String status = intent.getStringExtra(PowerConnectionReceiver.EXTRA_STATUS);
        txtStatusView.setText(status);
      }
    };
}
```